# Glmm and ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, plot, glm, glmm

How can I plot a glmm with a Fixed Effect Average Curve?

```
glmm_raras <- glmmTMB(rarity ~ width + (1|article/bacias), family = 
beta_family, data = rarity_df) 
summary(glmm_raras)

gg_raridade <- ggplot(data = df_rarity_ggplot, aes(x = width, y = 
rarity)) +
geom_point(pch = 19, cex = 1.5, alpha = 0.5, aes(color = 
as.factor(bacias))) + 
geom_smooth(method = "glm", se=F, aes(col = as.factor(bacias), group 
= bacias))+
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 50), ylim = c(0, 1))+ 
labs(y = "Rarity",
   x = "Width(m)") +
scale_color_manual(values = cores)+
guides(color = guide_legend(ncol = 1))+
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,10,20,30,40,50))+
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.5), legend.key 
= element_rect(fill = "white"),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "grey90"),   
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "grey90"), 
    axis.title = element_text(size = 14, family = "sans"), 
    legend.position = "none")+
facet_wrap(~bacias)
```

I had thought of a formula like this:

```
fixcoef_rari <- fixef(glmm_raras)
formula <- exp(fixcoef_rari$cond[1] + fixcoef_rari$cond[2]*x)
```

but I have no idea if thats correct or how to do it.

I tried this function with stat_function but it seems wrong...